# How can I install opencv with option --with-nonfree using brew

Tags: opencv, homebrew

I installed opencv using brew on Mac. I need some option like nonfree, the command as follows:

```
brew install opencv --with-nonfree
```

But, this does't work. It just show:

```
Warning: opencv: this formula has no --with-nonfree option so it will be ignored!
```

Must I compile and install opencv from source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew [already builds OpenCV with `-DOPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON` for you](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/09c4dd5f89931a49fb2679df3ad05d38b96372e1/Formula/opencv.rb#L60), so you don’t need to specify it:

```
brew install opencv
```

Use `brew options opencv` to get its options. Here it doesn’t output anything because Homebrew doesn’t support any option for that formula.

Comment: Thanks. Would you please tell me where the official description is?

Comment: @Ayoung Do you mean the Homebrew package (formula)? I linked it in my answer; the list of options is here: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/09c4dd5f89931a49fb2679df3ad05d38b96372e1/Formula/opencv.rb#L60

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I saw it as per your link.